# Why is F($\beta$) a subfield of F($\alpha$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

There is a corollary in my book that says:

> If E is an extension field of F, $\alpha \in E$ is algebraic over $F$,
>   and $\beta \in F(\alpha)$, then $\deg(\beta,F)$ divides
>   $\deg(\alpha,F)$.

**In the proof they use that $F(\beta)\leq F(\alpha)$. But why do we have this?** I mean since $\alpha$ is algebraic over F, and $\beta \in F(\alpha)$. We know that $\beta=c_0+\ldots+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}.$

Now let $\gamma \in F(\beta)$. **If $\beta$ is algebraic over F**. Then $\gamma=d_0+\ldots +d_{m-1}\beta^{m-1}$. Now we can substitute $\beta$ with $\beta=c_0+\ldots+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}$ and use that $\alpha^n=-a_{n-1}-\ldots-a_0$.(This comes from irr($\alpha$,F)).

**But what if $\beta$ is transcendental over F? How do I show it then?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field $F(\beta)$ can be viewed/defined as the intersection of all subfields of $K$ containing $\beta$ for some ambient field $K$ containing $F$ and $\beta$.  Thus $F(\beta) \subset F(\alpha)$ follows directly from $\beta \in F(\alpha)$.  You can also see this directly: if $\beta$ is in a field containing $F$, then so too is any rational function in $\beta$ with $F$ coefficients.

It is a also a fact (although the argument might not be immediately obvious) that if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, then any polynomial in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $F$ is also algebraic over $F$.  This means that $\beta $ cannot be transcendental as long as $\alpha$ is algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: for clarity, I'll try to reason constructively (avoid things like intersecting all subfields containing $\beta$) and in very small steps.

If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, then $\dim_F(F(\alpha))$ is finite (namely the degree$~n$ of the minimal polynomial of$~\alpha$). This was given, so we are working in an $n$-dimensional space over$~F$.

Consider the successive powers $\beta^0=1,\beta^1=\beta,\beta^2,\beta^3,\ldots$, of which initial portions will be linearly independent up to some point, but must then become linearly dependent (certainly $[1,\beta,\ldots,\beta^n]$ is linearly dependent, being $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space). Let $d>0$ be minimal such that $[1,\beta,\ldots,\beta^d]$ is linearly dependent. By minimality, the linear dependence relation involves $\beta^d$ with a nonzero coefficient, and dividing by that coefficient we obtain a relation that involves $\beta^n$ with coefficient$~d$, in other words, a monic polynomial $P$ of degree$~d$ such that $P[\beta]=0$. This shows that $\beta$ is certainly algebraic.

Now the $F$-subspace generated by $1,\beta,\ldots,\beta^{d-1}$ is closed under multiplication by $\beta$ (check this on the generating vectors), and therefore contains all positive powers of $\beta$, so it is equal to $F[\beta]$. This is *a priori* a subring of $F(\alpha)$ (its elements are all polynomials in$~\beta$, and as such it is closed under addition and multiplication). However one sees that $F[\beta]$ is a field by a general result that says that if a ring$~R$ is both (1) an integral domain, and (2) finite dimensional over some sub-*field* $F$ of $R$, then $R$ is itself a field. The following proof of this fact is simple linear algebra: consider multiplication by a nonzero element $r\in R$ as $F$-linear operator $m_r:R\to R$. By hypothesis (1) $m_r$ is injective, so that $\det_F(m_r)\neq0$, but then $m_r$ is also surjective, in particular there is $s\in R$ such that $m_r(s)=1\in R$, which means that $s$ is the inverse of$~r$.

There is a somewhat more constructive version of the argument that $F[\beta]$ is a field when $\beta$ is algebraic. The fact that $F[\beta]$ is an integral domain (as before because we are inside the field $F(\alpha)$) implies that the minimal polynomial $P\in F[X]$ of$~\beta$ is *irreducible*: if one had $P=Q_1Q_2$ with $Q_1,Q_2$ both of degree strictly less than $\deg(P)$, then by minimality of$~P$ neither $Q_1[\beta]$ nor $Q_2[\beta]$ would be zero, but $ Q_1[\beta].Q_2[\beta]=P[\beta]=0$, contradicting the integral domain condition. Now any nonzero element of $F[\beta]$ can be written uniquely as $Q[\beta]$ with $Q$ nonzero and $\deg(Q)<\deg(P)$. Then $\gcd(P,Q)=1$, whence there exist Bézout coefficients $S,T\in F[X]$ such that $SP+TQ=1$, and evaluating this at $X=\beta$ gives $T[\beta]Q[\beta]=1$, showing that our nonzero element $ Q[\beta]\in F[\beta]$ is invertible.

Comment: But there you use that the space is spanned by the $\beta$-vectors. But this you do not know before you know that $\beta$ is algebraic?

Comment: @user119615 Well whatever the subfield is, it must be finite dimensional. Concretely, you first argue that the _ring_ $F[\beta]\subseteq F(\alpha)$ (which is certainly spanned by the powers of $\beta$) is finite dimensional, therefore $\beta$ is algebraic, but then $F[\beta]$ is in fact a field, so equal to $F(\beta)$.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very difficult for me. Since we have that $\beta \in F(\alpha)$, we know that every polynomial of $\beta$ with F coefficients is in $F(\alpha)$. Hence $F[\beta] \in F(\alpha)$. But since $F(\alpha)$ is a finite dimensional vector space, there must then be a finite number of $\beta$ that span $F[\beta]$? Are you using that $F[\beta]$ over F, is a subsvectorspace of $F(\alpha)$ over F?But how does it follow that $\beta$ is algebraic?

Comment: @user119615: Yes, that's completely right. $F[\beta]$ is by definition spanned by _all_ powers of $\beta$, but since one is confined to a finite-dim vector space $F(\alpha)$, they cannot all be linearly independent, and  finitely many span $F[\beta]$. In particular there is some first $\beta^d$ that is a linear combination of $1,\beta,\ldots,\beta^{d-1}$. But that means some polynomial of degree $d$ in $\beta$ is $0$, so $\beta$ is algebraic. And then $F[\beta]$ is in fact a field. (This is a standard argument about being algebraic).

Comment: Thanks, I must appologize that I take this so slow. But why do you then go from that $F[\beta]$ is a ring to a field? A field is a ring, with a unity that is commutative and every element has an inverse, since 1 is a polynomial we have that we have a unity?, and since F is a field we have commutativity?, but how do we get that every element has an inverse? I have seen a proof that uses that if $\beta$ is algebraic, then $F(\beta)$ is a field that is spanned by some finite numbers of powers of $\beta$, this proof uses max ideal and irreducible polynomials, is that what you use?

Comment: But then it seems that we still have the case that we must conclude that $\beta$ is either algebraic or transcendental before we conclude that $F(\beta) \subseteq F(\alpha)$?

Comment: @user119615: (1) Since $F(\beta)$ is obtained by ensuring that it contains all polynomials in $\beta$, and then that all nonzero elements have an inverse, and since the latter holds _everywhere_ in $F(\alpha)$, it is clear that $F(\beta)\subseteq F(\alpha)$ in any case. This excludes the possibility that $\beta$ is transcendental, as that would make $F(\beta)$ infinite dimensional. (2) the proof that $\beta$ algebraic implies $F[\beta]$ is a field can be given without using maximal ideals; I'll extend my answer.